# Spring Scheduler cpu usage

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

I've noticed that after i start using the `@EnableScheduling` and `@Scheduled` annotation the cpu usage on the host which the JVM is running stays fairly high. Can anyone provide any explanation to this? Reading the documentation it says that there is only 1 thread for the `TaskExecutor`, so unless this thread is running all the time I don't see how the cpu usage could be this high.

The `@Scheduled` method queries an http api and gets on average about 20 json lines back which get converted to objects and then stored into a database, when running the method without the annotation and tracking metrics around it it takes at worst 2 seconds on an AWS t2.medium. The cpu usage jumps higher when this method gets executed, but during the interval period the cpu usage still remains high.The scheduling interval is every 30 min.

Documentation I'm referring to:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.htm

Comment: Well...what does your `@Scheduled` method do?

Comment: I do not think that the problem is with Springs Scheduler infrastructure, I think the problem is likely related to what you used it for, so please post some code and explain what you try to achieve.

Comment: What rate do you use to schedule ?

Comment: updated with edits to attempt to clarify gaps

Answer (score -1):

Try taking a few thread dumps of your JVM (with [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) for example). You will see what each thread is doing. If you take thread dumps every 10 seconds and you see a thread that is always in the same piece of code, that a good candidate for your problem.

Comment: FYI: pressing [ctrl] in combination with [pause/break] in the command line of a java application will create a thread dump